# Edit category listing in adding a new post screen of WordPress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-admin

I have 2 menus to add a new post to Wordpress database, one is type "post" of default Wordpress and one custom type is "listing".

These posts belong to different categories type. And the thing I want to do is, how can I customize "category selection" when I add a new post in default WordPress screen so it can have both categories of type "post" itself as well as all categories for "listing" type.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without code we probably won't be able to help you.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.